# matching async api call results to requests

Tags: c#, async-await, httpclient

I'm trying to implement an async api call using httpclient. I've got the call working using a dictionary with my key pair value to write back to a database tying it back to the correct source record.

I'm stuck at how do I relate the calls back to the original request for updating.

Here's the meat of the work:

```
var s_urlList = xmltogo.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<DataRow, int, string>(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<string>(0)), row => row.Field<string>(1));


                    IEnumerable<Task<string>> downloadTasksQuery =
                    from url in s_urlList.Values
                    select CallAPI(url);

                    List<Task<string>> downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToList();

                    while (downloadTasks.Any())
                    {
                       Task<string> finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks);

                        downloadTasks.Remove(finishedTask);

                        string XMLResult = finishedTask.Result.ToString();

                    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: why not just use `await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasksQuery);`, then iterate over each task to check for results.

Comment: I'd  like to do work as each call completes.There will be hundreds. Still how do I relate s-urlList.Key to finnished task?.

Answer (score 0):

I need to pass the key and the xml through to my method as 2 parameters and then return it back:

```
Dictionary<int, string> s_urlList = xmltogo.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<DataRow, int, string>(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<string>(0)), row => row.Field<string>(1));


                    IEnumerable<Task<(int,string)>> downloadTasksQuery =
                    from url in s_urlList
                    select CallAPI(url.Key, url.Value);

                    List<Task<(int,string)>> downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToList();

                    while (downloadTasks.Any())
                    {
                       Task<(int, string)> finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks);


                        downloadTasks.Remove(finishedTask);

                        string XMLResult = finishedTask.Result.Item2.ToString();
                        int key = finishedTask.Result.Item1;
                        Console.WriteLine("key: " + key.ToString() + "XML: " + XMLResult);
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 var s_urlList = xmltogo.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary<DataRow, int, string>(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<string>(0)), row => row.Field<string>(1));

        List<Tuple<string, string>> xmlResults =new  List<Tuple<string,string>>() 
        IEnumerable<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>> downloadTasksQuery =
        from url in s_urlList.Values
        select CallAPI(url).ContinueWith(x=> xmlResults.Add(url, x.Result));

        List<Task<string>> downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToList();

       await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);
        foreach (var xmlResult in xmlResults)
        {
            string url = xmlResult.Item1,
                   XMLResult = xmlResult.Item2;
            // use your result here
        }
```

Comment: Yes, that's where the result action should be. But how do I relate the result to the request s_urlList.Key to update the correct record in my db.

Comment: You can do in continue with or in for each.